# Pass two variable argument list

Tags: python

I know this works very well:

```
def locations(city, *other_cities): 
    print(city, other_cities)
```

Now I need two  variable argument list, like

```
def myfunction(type, id, *arg1, *arg2):
    # do somethong
    other_function(arg1)

    #do something
    other_function2(*arg2)
```

But Python does not allow to use this twice

Comment: Can you give an example of how you wish to call the function?

Comment: How would Python know if an argument should be in `arg1` or `arg2` if both are variadic?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not possible because `*arg` captures *all positional args* from that position on. So by definition, a second `*args2` would always be empty.

An easy solution would be passing two tuples:

```
def myfunction(type, id, args1, args2):
    other_function(args1)
    other_function2(args2)
```

and call it like this:

```
myfunction(type, id, (1,2,3), (4,5,6))
```

In case the two functions expect positional arguments instead of a single argument, you would call them like this:

```
def myfunction(type, id, args1, args2):
    other_function(*arg1)
    other_function2(*arg2)
```

This would have the advantage that you can use **any** iterable, even a generator, when calling `myfunction` since the called functions would never get in contact with the passed iterables.

---

If you really want to work with two variable argument lists you need some kind of separator. The following code uses `None` as the separator:

```
import itertools
def myfunction(type, id, *args):
    args = iter(args)
    args1 = itertools.takeuntil(lambda x: x is not None, args)
    args2 = itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x is None, args)
    other_function(args1)
    other_function2(args2)
```

It would be used like this:

```
myfunction(type, id, 1,2,3, None, 4,5,6)
```

Comment: Yes, any iterable is fine as long as `other_function` does not rely on specific behaviour of e.g. a list or a tuple.

Comment: Instead of a seperator, a different type could also be used to determine which arguments belong where.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two dictionaries instead.

Comment: s/dictionaries/lists or tuples/. Dicts would be used for kwargs, but he's using posargs

Comment: @ThiefMaster I'm not talking about ** magic, but about just using dictionaries with parameters. I don't know really why the author needs to pass two posargs lists

Comment: This answer is not detailed enough. Provide some code to improve its quality.